# Use column number as role in DelegateChooser

Tags: qt, delegates, qml

Working in QML 5, I wish to format my table content (columns) differently based on the column number.  For example, col 1 holds a string, col 2 holds a checkmark, col 3 holds and image. etc.

I was hoping to use the column number in my delegatechooser but it fails (never matches a roleValue).  Though if I print model.column in the delegate it does show my column number.

How can I use column number in my chooser?

```
 DelegateChooser {
        id: chooser
        role: "model.column"
        DelegateChoice { roleValue: "0"; ItemDelegate { ... } }
        DelegateChoice { roleValue: "1"; SwitchDelegate { ... } }
        DelegateChoice { roleValue: "2"; SwipeDelegate { ... } }
    }
```

Comment: Does it work if you just use `role: "column"`?

Answer (score 1):

The `role` property of `DelegateChooser` is not the one you need.

You need the `column` property of `DelegateChoice`:

```
DelegateChooser {
    DelegateChoice { column: 0; ItemDelegate { ... } }
    DelegateChoice { column: 1; SwitchDelegate { ... } }
    DelegateChoice { column: 2; SwipeDelegate { ... } }
}
```